# Why is my output empty when I convert a set into an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am solving [Leetcode 26 Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/) with the following instructions:

> Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that
> each element appear only once and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
> modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

My solution was to first create a set, iterate every number within the array and add each to the set and simply convert the set into an array.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  let set = new Set();
  for (let num of nums) {
    set.add(num);
  }
  return Array.from(set); 
};
```

When I `console.log` my array, it outputs the answer Leetcode is looking for but when I submit, the output is `[]`. Why is this happening?

Comment: *"you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory."* Creating a `set` violates that instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently creating a `set` violates the instruction that I must modify the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the primary question, You better use `set.values()` to get all the values from set, like this

```
return [...set.values()]
```

But as you stated creating a new set will take extra memory and violates O(1) memory;
A simple solution would be iterate over elements, and keep the previous element in a variable, if current element is equal to previous element, remove current element. Then return array length in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) return 0;
    let i =0;
    for(let j= 1; j < nums.length ; j++){
        if(nums[j] != nums[i]){
             nums.splice(i,i+1);
            i++;
            }
    }
  
    return i +1;
};

nums =[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4];

console.log("Count :",removeDuplicates(nums),nums)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use reduce method and return the length of the array.

```
var removeDuplicates = function (nums) {
  return nums.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    if (accumulator.indexOf(currentValue) === -1) {
      accumulator.push(currentValue);
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []).length;
};
```

Or a different approach using the set

```
var removeDuplicates = function (nums) {
    return [...new Set(nums)].length
}
```

Comment: running this solution with the test case fails.

Comment: may I know what is the failure message?